# Spring MVC: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn spring mvc usign a "Spring MVC: Beginner's Guide" book. After reading first chapter and doing exactly what it asks me to do my code does not work (as always during learning from tutorial/book). My code does not see my jsp page:

[image]

My web.xml file:

```
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My DefaultServlet-servlet.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

welcome.jsp :

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Witaj</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>${greeting}</h1>
                <p>${tagline}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

HomeController.java:

```
package com.packt.webstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome in shop!");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "Unique shop!");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
  <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
</project>
```

And lastly, my folder hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Please try only `http://localhost:8080/`. And if you can, post `pom.xml` too.

Comment: Added pom.xml, when I go for http://localhost:8080/ it shows the server welcome page

Comment: @HTF How do you deploy your application? Do you have a Tomcat or JBoss?

Comment: @awagenhoffer I have a Tomcat.

Comment: @HTF If you start your application with mark as deployable (on the war), could you reach it with the url http://localhost:8080/webstore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/